How to implement an DB index to allow intersection queries on a database which does not support compound keys?
I am creating a DB that indexes JSONs on top of a key value storage engine (LMDB or somewhat similar).
When a new JSON needs to be indexed, I will create an entry for each field (AKA, JSON key), for example, for the field "firstname=123" I will create a reverse index "123 = jsonid".
So this allows me to query all json objects in which firstname equals 123.
My question is, how do I structure my indexes, in order to be able to answer a compound query (example firstname = X and lastname = Y)
In other words, how do I structure my index on top of a key value DB like LMDB (which uses a sorted tree), to allow for compound queries when I dont have a compound index.
How do relational DBs do this?
Just to be clear: I am not asking about pre-indexed queries.

Generally, by requiring predefined indexes.

If your on a good RDBMS, you might also have the option of bitmap scans. (Postgres and SQL Server I know can do that)

@DocBrown Thats actually fairly simple to handle with a b-tree (A,B) index. You look up the first A between B and X, then you scan under that item for values between C and Y, when you hit Y, you go up the tree to scan to the next A and then repeat for items between C and Y. And repeat for all a keys.

The indexing strategies of DBs/Engines like Postgres, SQLite, Lucene are well documented. Note that there's a large difference between creating indices with specific queries in mind (needed in SQL DBs, but can be very efficient) vs creating indices that are supposed to help with unknown queries (e.g. Lucene indexes all fields separately). If you have multiple indices that help with part of the query, you may be able to use set operations to reduce the number of candidates before loading the actual rows/documents. This is easiest to do if your index data structure supports range queries.

Are you only able to have one index?

@user1937198: the question you need to answer to the OP is: is which kind of index do they have to create so the DB will behave that way.

Sorry for not commenting earlier, I have some compound indexed already, but I wasn’t clear.

I am trying to answer  "WHERE A='X' AND B='Y'" but in the case in which I don't have an index for "AB".

I have updated the question to be clearer

@SamuelE.: so what you are asking is specifically about key-value stores like LMDB which only provide fast lookup for keys, but not for combined columns? Please double check whether my edit expresses what you have in mind.

@DocBrown looks good, thank you

I find your question a little confusing because the example solution you give is an essentially an example of what you say you are looking to do.  Because of that, I'm a little uncertain if this is what you are looking for, but perhaps it will at least give you a starting point or, if not, help you formulate what you are trying to ask here.
Database indexing is a pretty mature area and not one that I can claim any expertise in, but there are two basic ways to go about this that amon alludes to in his comment on the question.

Build an index specific to the set of fields you want to optimize lookups for
Build separate indexes for each field, search against them separately then find the intersection of the results

#1 is basically what you describe in your question. I don't think you need more explanation for that. I'm not sure munging strings is the right approach but that's just a quibble.
#2 Might be what you are after and that's what I am going to focus on.
You have a collection JSON documents and you want to find all where field aay has the value 'ecks' and field bee has the value 'why'.
Create an aay index and a bee index.  For now, let's assume these are lexically ordered.  Search the aay index for the value 'ecks' and capture the set of pointers/indexes/ids. Let's assume that you use a binary search, so log N on average.  You do the same on for 'why' on the bee index.  Also log N on average.  Now you have two sets of pointers/indexes/ids. All that remains is to find the intersection of those two sets. The performance of that will depend on the data structure they are stored in. Time complexity for that is left as an exercise to the reader.

The standard datastructure for storing the set of rows from an index scan for intersection is the page bitmap. Then you can just And the bitmaps to get the intersection and discard any pages where the result is zero.

Im sorry about it not being clear. I have updated the question. But the summary is that I am trying to answer the query when I dont have a pre-built compound index on the fields.

The example I gave was to create a compound index, so it only solves the problem for a predefined set of compound queries, which uses a lot of space, and is limiting

So, from your answer I understand, that I have to get all entries in both indexes and do an intersection, which means that I must have enough memory in order to accommodate at least the biggest index + the intersection. Is this assumption correct?

@SamuelE. ideally, but not necessarily, so long as you have some way of identifying small enough groups of keys. Postgres handles that in two ways: Rather than a single bitmap, they store a bitmap per page, only recording the pages that have any results. The assumption being the key is selective enough that a significant proportion of pages will have no matching values.

And secondly, if the amount of memory that would use goes over a threshold, they discard the bitmap, and only store the set of pages. Then double check which keys in that page match when reading after computing the intersection of pages that contain a key that matches. Sometimes you might get a page that has one key that matches A, and one different key that matches B but not both, but thats seen as an acceptable cost. And the assumption is that the memory to table size ratio is big enough that you will always have enough room to store that.

"which means that I must have enough memory in order to accommodate at least the biggest index + the intersection." No, not necessarily. Let's say your index consists of the field value and a list of ids of records containing that value. If the list is sorted, to find the intersection, you only need to compare one value at a time. That is, you read the first value from each list, if they are the same, you emit or store that value and advance to the next value in each index. If not, the lesser of the 2 is discarded and you advance just that index.

When you expect queries like firstname = X and lastname = Y, and the infrastructure you have at hand allows only single key lookups, probably the most simple and efficient solution is to build a compound index by yourself. This can be achieved easily by simply concatenating the strings firstname and lastname by some separator character in the middle which is ideally not part of the allowed character set for these two attributes, or at least very unlikely to appear there.
For example, let' s assume ";" is a forbidden character, then you can index by the keys firstname + ";" + lastname, and a lookup for firstname='X' AND lastname='Y' will just be a lookup for the key 'X;Y'.
Of course, when no characters are forbidden for these attributes, you may have to encode the separator character  in the data first before creating the lookup key, or you may have to deal with the fact that a lookup for 'X;;Y' can return results with firstname='X;' and lastname='Y' as well as firstname='X' and lastname=';Y' (and sort out the unwanted items afterwards).
Note that doing two lookups for items with firstname='X', then all items with lastname='Y', and finally build their intersection might be fast enough in certain real world cases. Still it is not nearly as efficient as creating a combined index (especially when you have to deal with a large number of records). You may read my answer here to understand what to expect when dealing with hundreds of millions of records and indexes which cover only one attribute out of two.

Thanks for the answer but I was talking about cases in which I don’t have a pre-defined compound query

@SamuelE.: sorry, but that does not make any sense. When you are going to create indexes, then you expect certain kind of queries, otherwise you would not add any index in the first place.
